# Denormalise head count break down using pivot and unpivot

Tags: sql, database-design

I have roles and master_headcount tables.
In role tables I have 16 rows(not fixed for sure).
In master_headcount table I have break downs according to working type, month and year

```
role table:

Id  name
1   Role1
2   Role2

master_headcount table:

Id  headcountvalue  workingtype month   year
1   3               fulltime    1       2019
2   5               parttime    1       2019
3   10              fulltime    2       2019
4   15              parttime    2       2019

master_headcount-role table:

master_headcountId  roleId  rolebased_headcountvalue
"1,2"               1       2
"1,2"               2       6
"3,4"               1       11
"3,4"               2       14
```

in application I have this ui to "CRUD" relevant records:

[image]

I need to break down master_headcount table rows for roles.

I could image one solution add rows to master table, however I want to have separate table for "denormalise" tables.

I could guess also I need to pivot/unpivot operations which is I am not good at.
At least for pivoting operations I need model my requirements.

My question how I can model and design my tables that I could have properly `master_headcountId` modeled that I don't have "1,2" or "3,4" values

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but if I do, then you just have to have twice as many rows in your `master_headcount-role` table.

This:

```
master_headcountId  roleId  rolebased_headcountvalue
"1,2"               1       2
```

Would become this:

```
master_headcountId  roleId  rolebased_headcountvalue
1                   1       2
2                   1       2
```

And so on for all the other rows like it.

Comment: I could immediately say this works for retrieving values, however I remember that I was stuck inserting values. Actually my application ui screen shots makes me think this is not enough

Comment: That's a different question.   This is a design question.   If you want to ask about inserting, create another question showing what you were trying to do and why it didn't work.

Comment: I expressed that in my question _in application I have this ui to "CRUD" relevant records_, I am thinking about adding more details. Maybe adding one more many-to-many relation solves my prob.

Comment: The image of the UI is useless without the code behind it.   There isn't nearly enough information in this question to help you with inserts.